# multipass management tools?

Tags: multipass

Is there no utility by which the operator might find out how much disk is being used by a collection of multipass images?  The only way I have been able to view anything is to look at `multipass list -vvvv` and wade through reams of information looking for disk sizes.

For example, in docker:

```
me@mybox:~$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY                     TAG          IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
alpine                         build        9443c4e84eaf   About an hour ago   1.03GB
alpine                         run          25a4aa8e91d7   4 hours ago         53.3MB
ubuntu23kde                    v1           d9ee676502df   4 days ago          2.88GB
ubuntudev                      qt642        939488404c95   7 days ago          1.2GB
alpine-container               v1           b2f8d4361b88   7 days ago          1.03GB
portnavigator/port-navigator   1.1.0        314caea26d7e   5 weeks ago         168MB
alpine                         latest       8ca4688f4f35   6 weeks ago         7.34MB
docker/disk-usage-extension    0.2.8        e2e81f16dc58   2 months ago        2.82MB
```

Is there no analog in multipass?

Comment: Lots of downvotes, without the courtesy of a comment?

Comment: I'd be tempted to utilise either `multipass info` or `multipass list` as per your comments. Both are capable of outputting in `yaml` or `json` format so are a `jq` command away from what you want. If you can share an example output, I could probably suggest something. I'm not near my multipass installation at the moment.

Comment: Yes, the mystery of down-votes strikes me as well.  Dare I compare multipass utils with docker utils?  If you want to compete, management tools, even the simplest of them are vitally important.  If I have to go and write software to unravel your output into something comprehensible and useful, that's a FAIL in my book.

Comment: Perhaps it's just a reading comprehension issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`multipass info <imagename>`

is the closest I have come to useful information but the format is terrible.

Using the `--format` switch with `csv`, `yaml`, or `json` value gives other formatting, none of which are a simple table for a quick view.  I think that would be a good addition to the `--format` option.